# How do I count the number of ocurrences, considering a range (bigger than x, smaler than y), in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: math, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet in LibreOffice. What I need to know, is how to calculate the number of occurrences in a range, for columns D and E. For example, how many times a number in column D is bigger than 3, but smaller than 5. The return should calculate how many times, a value appears and return true to this condition.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the COUNTIFS function (or CONT.SES, if you're using the Portuguese version). The syntax is very similar to that of COUNTIF / CONT.SE.

For your example, it would be:

```
=COUNTIFS(D:D;">3";D:D;"<5")
```

I think this function has been available since version 4.0, but I can't say for sure: I currently use version 5.0.5 and I can say it's there.